# Make slider from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I am going to create a simple slider from available JSON object. I want to scroll 3 item i.e. `3 keys of JSON` in single click either left or right.

Example: If I clicked right arrow then I want to fetch 0 to 2 keys of JSON and display image and if again right arrow then 3 to 6 and so on. Similarly in case of left arrow clicked. I want to make negative loop from current position of JSONkeys like 6 to 3.

I tried my code But its not working well.

```
var recents = "";
var imges = "";
var imge = "";
var recent_prod = <?php echo $recent_prod; ?>;
$("#num").html(recent_prod.length);
for(var a = 0; a < 3; a++)
{
    imges = recent_prod[a].image;
    imge = imges.split[","];
    recents += '<a href="' + base_url + 'init/product/' + recent_prod[a].id + '">'+
                    '<div class="related_prod_thumb">' +
                        '<div class="related_prod_img">'+
                            '<span class="helper"></span>'+
                            '<img src="' + base_url + 'uploads/thumbnail/' + imges + '" width="100">'+
                        '</div><div class="related_prod_title">' + recent_prod[a].title +'</div>'+
                        '<div class="related_prod_price">' + 'Rs. ' + recent_prod[a].price + '</div></div></a>';
}
$("#recent_views").html(recents);

$(document).on("click", ".rightarr", function(){
    var next_recent_prod = "";
    var next = a + 3;
    for(var i = a; i < next; i++)
    {
        imges = recent_prod[i].image;
        imge = imges.split[","];
        next_recent_prod += '<a href="' + base_url + 'init/product/' + recent_prod[i].id + '">'+
                        '<div class="related_prod_thumb">' +
                            '<div class="related_prod_img">'+
                                '<span class="helper"></span>'+
                                '<img src="' + base_url + 'uploads/thumbnail/' + imges + '" width="100">'+
                            '</div><div class="related_prod_title">' + recent_prod[i].title +'</div>'+
                            '<div class="related_prod_price">' + 'Rs. ' + recent_prod[i].price + '</div></div></a>';
        a = a + 1;
    }
    $("#num").html(a);

    $("#recent_views").html(next_recent_prod);
});

$(document).on("click", ".leftarr", function(){
    var next_recent_prod = "";
    var pre = a - 3;
    for(var i = pre; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        imges = recent_prod[i].image;
        imge = imges.split[","];
        next_recent_prod += '<a href="' + base_url + 'init/product/' + recent_prod[i].id + '">'+
                        '<div class="related_prod_thumb">' +
                            '<div class="related_prod_img">'+
                                '<span class="helper"></span>'+
                                '<img src="' + base_url + 'uploads/thumbnail/' + imges + '" width="100">'+
                            '</div><div class="related_prod_title">' + recent_prod[i].title +'</div>'+
                            '<div class="related_prod_price">' + 'Rs. ' + recent_prod[i].price + '</div></div></a>';
    }
    $("#num").html(a);

    $("#recent_views").html(next_recent_prod);
    a = i;
});
```

With this code I get negative keys of JSON when clicked left. That is -1 but its doesn't exists in JSON. So I get error `TypeError`. Also Its not working as expected
Any help would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What should happen when left arrow is clicked and the key is 0, should go down from the last product?

Comment: No, It should Stop the slider and arrow key could be disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems your going from `a` to `next` which is `a+3` for the right arrow, but for the left arrow you're going from 0 to `pre` which is supposed to be `a-3`. You probably mean:

   ```
   for(var i = a-1; i >= pre; i--)
   ```
2. You have `a = i` after the loop in your left arrow click, when that loop ends the value of `i` will be -1 (or if corrected #1 it'll be one below the desired value), So you probably would want:

   ```
   a = i + 1;
   ```

   Or like you do for the right arrow, have it insides your loop:

   ```
   a = a - 1; //or in short a--;
   ```
3. For left arrow you need to check whether it reaches zero and if so only show the first 3 items, disable the left arrow, etc:

   ```
   var pre;
   if(a > 2)
       pre = a - 3;
   else {
       pre = 2;
       //disable left & make sure you enable it when right is clicked.
   }
   ```
4. Do the same for the right arrow, check whether it exceeds the length:

   ```
   //not sure about 4, try 3 or 2 maybe if it doesn't work
   if(a < recent_prod.length - 4)
       next = a + 3;
   else {
       next = recent_prod.length - 3;
       //disable right & make sure you enable it when left is clicked.
   }
   ```